# uploading content (images) with the Salesforce Marketing Cloud REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

How exactly do you create a new asset with the salesforce REST API?
I've tried the following with no luck - does the content-type needs to be different?

*imageData is the base64 representation of a jpg file*

```
url = 'https://***.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets'

headers = {
    'Authorization':'Bearer {}'.format(accessToken),
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
}

res = requests.post(url, headers=headers,
                   data = {
                       "name":"204752364",
                       "assetType":{"id":23,"name":"jpg"},
                       "file":imageData
                   })
```

I get a bad request error

Edits:
I'm using the requests library in python to make these requests.
Host is https://**.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/
I was following along the official documentation found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/file_upload.htm)
I don't think the image size is an issue (its less than 100kb)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, I don't think there's really enough detail for anyone to be able to give you an accurate answer. Basically, the more details you can provide, the better. Knowing the url that you're trying to post this to (and seeing the code that's handling the request if this is a custom apex rest resource), and what you're using to make the request will probably help. Knowing the size of your image is also probably an important detail (filesize can be an issue, and base64 encoding takes up 1.33x more space than the un-encoded data).

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include more detail (comments aren't really a good place for additional details due to their temporary nature, limited length, and limited formatting options).

Comment: In general, your payload looks correct, assuming that imageData is the actual Base64 value. Are you also passing in the Authorization token in the header? You only show the Content-Type (but missing that should give back the 'Unauthorized' error, so probably not it). To verify you are sending to `asset/v1/content/assets` and using POST method, right?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. Just had to pass the data as a json object, not a dict